# Node error while using node module usb and pcsclite

Tags: node.js, usb, node-modules, pcsc

I want to use the node module "usb" to connect with a printer and node module "pcsclite" to use a smartcard-reader.
When i use both modules node.exe exits with error code -1073740771 (0xc000041d).

Here is a little test program:

```
var usb = require('usb')

var PCSC = require('pcsclite')()
PCSC.on('reader', function (reader) {
    console.log('add reader')
    reader.on('status', function (status) {
        console.log('status: ' + status)
    })
    reader.on('error', function (err) { console.log('reader error: ' + err) })
    reader.on('end', function () { console.log('end') })
})
PCSC.on('error', function (err) { console.log('PCSC error: ' + err) })
```

When i remove the first line, the program works fine.

P.S.: I use nodejs 4.8.3, usb 1.3.1 and pcsclite 0.4.12

Comment: Found out, that the problem is already issued to nodejs on github.
It seem that the problem occure just with the node-usb module and USB smart-card-readers

https://github.com/tessel/node-usb/issues/285